# Add dynamics <tr> in the table in mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hello friends  I have a problem is that I want to show the return value of a field of the database in the table .. My problem is that it shows all the return values in one head .. I want only 8 numbers in each row Show me and dynamically add another line .. Thank you for your help

```html
  </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Tab3">


                    @if (ViewBag.ProductPartNumber != null)
                    {
                        List<ShowProductPartNumberViewModel> list = ViewBag.ProductPartNumber;

                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped">

                                <tbody>

                                    @foreach (var item in list)
                                    {

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>@item.ProductNumberTitle </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    }

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    }

                </div>
```

Comment: how many items you have in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        @for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i += 8)
        {
            var items = list.Skip(i).Take(8).ToList();
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            <tr>
                <td>
                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                       sb.Append(item.ProductNumberTitle)
                    }
                    sb.ToString();
               </td>
            </tr>

        }
```